# Topological nature of IEEE floating-point numbers

Tags: general-topology, continuity, floating-point, topological-semigroups

If IEEE floating-point numbers had countably infinite precisions, its domain would be:
$$
\{-\infty\}\cup\mathbb{R}^-\cup\{-0,+0\}\cup\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{+\infty\}\cup\{\text{NaN}\}
$$

Let's denote this $\mathbb{FP}$ and give $\mathbb{FP}^2$ the product topology.

The **addition** is defined as:

- $+0 + \pm0 = +0$
- $-0 + \pm0 = \pm0$ (double sign in same order)
- $x + (-x) = +0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$
- $\pm\infty + x = \pm\infty$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$(double sign in same order)
- $\pm\infty + \pm\infty = \pm\infty$ (double sign in same order)
- $\pm\infty + \mp\infty = \text{NaN}$ (double sign in same order)
- If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN.
- Addition is commutative.
- Otherwise, the usual addition in $\mathbb{R}$

The **negation** is defined as

- $-(\pm0) = \mp0$ (double sign in same order)
- $-(\pm\infty) = \mp\infty$ (double sign in same order)
- $-\text{NaN} = \text{NaN}$
- Otherwise, the usual negation in $\mathbb{R}$

Assume both addition and negation are continuous, as long as the subspaces $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbb{R}^-$ maintain the usual topology.

The main question is: Are the zeros topologically distinguishable?

**Note:** I actually want the "prettiest" topology that explains the behavior of IEEE floating-point numbers. This is such a subjective notion,  yet there are something I definitely don't want:

- Trivial topology (a separation axiom would prevent it)
- Discrete topology (connectedness or compactness would prevent it)

I wanted the $T_1$ axiom so badly, but I couldn't separate the zeros. That's where the above question emerged.

As a consequence, I want the topology to satisfy as many space properties as possible.

So there is an additional question. If the answer is "yes", what is the maximum number of satisfiable-at-once conditions below?:

- Addition is quotient. (perfectness is preferable)
- Negation is quotient. (perfectness is preferable)
- $\mathbb{FP}$ is $T_1$. (stronger separation axioms are preferable)
- $\mathbb{FP}$ is metrizable. (complete matrizability is preferable)
- $\mathbb{FP}$ is connected. (path-connectedness is preferable)
- $\mathbb{FP}$ is Lindelöf. (compactness is preferable)
- $\mathbb{FP}$ is second-countable. (first-countablility is preferable)
- $\mathbb{FP}$ has a countable dense subset.

I *might've* also concerned about other operations, such as multiplication, reciprocal, absolute value function, signum function, transcendental functions, or special functions. But that *really* should be a story for another day...

Comment: Why the downvote? This is for the academy contest next year. The answerer has the authorship.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why post something for a contest in public like this?

Comment: @MarkS. Because the problem is too hard.

Comment: The case where we keep the usual topology seems to be trivial: Note that the map $\tau_{x}$ given by $\tau_x(y)=y+(-x)$ is a homeomorphism for $x\in \mathbb{R}^+\cup \mathbb{R}^-,$ with explicit inverse given by $\tau_x^{-1}=\tau_{-x}$. Thus, if we maintain the usual topology on these factors, then $\{+0\}=\tau_x(\{x\})$ is closed. But then, the complement of $\{+0\}$ is an open set contain $-0$, but not $+0$. Hence, they are topologically distinguishable.

Comment: A trivial case of connected and compact topology on ${\Bbb F\Bbb P}$ is the antidiscrete topology.

Comment: How is addition commutative between $+0$ and $-0$?

Comment: @Joppy $+0+(-0)=(-0)+(+0)=+0$.

Comment: Why do you change the question? Now the comment from @WoolierThanThou above is no longer a partial answer...

Comment: @supinf Sorry for that. I'll preserve the original question.

Comment: Can you point to a definition of a quotient (or perfect) group operation? I cannot make sense of the requirement "Addition is quotient. (perfectness is preferable)". Thanks!

Comment: @Aldoggen "Quotient" as in "quotient map". A quotient map is continuous and surjective, and maps saturated open sets to open sets.